# Read from file hexadecimal number and change their representation style

Tags: assembly, hex, mips

I want to write a program changing the notation of all hexadecimal numbers found in an assembly source file from traditional (h) to C-style (0x).
I have started the coding part but am not sure how can I detect the hexadecimal numbers and eventually change the style and save it back in the file...

I have started writing the program..

```
## Mips program  - 

.data
fin:   .ascii ""      # filename for input
msg0:   .asciiz "aaaa"
msg1:   .asciiz "Please enter the input file name:"
buffer: .asciiz ""
.text

#-----------------------
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, msg1
    syscall

    li $v0, 8
    la $a0, fin
    li $a1, 21
    syscall

    jal fileRead            #read from file
    move $s1, $v0           #$t0 = total number of bytes

    li $t0, 0   # Loop counter

loop:
    bge $t0, $s1, end           #if end of file reached OR if there is an error in the file
    lb $t5, buffer($t0)         #load next byte from file

    jal checkhexa       #check for hexadecimal numbers

    addi $t0, $t0, 1            #increment loop counter

j loop

end:

    jal output
    jal fileClose

    li $v0, 10
    syscall

fileRead:
    # Open file for reading
    li   $v0, 13       # system call for open file
    la   $a0, fin      # input file name
    li   $a1, 0        # flag for reading
    li   $a2, 0        # mode is ignored
    syscall            # open a file 
    move $s0, $v0      # save the file descriptor 

    # reading from file just opened
    li   $v0, 14       # system call for reading from file
    move $a0, $s0      # file descriptor 
    la   $a1, buffer   # address of buffer from which to read
    li   $a2, 100000   # hardcoded buffer length
    syscall            # read from file

jr $ra
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is (in pseudocode):

```
while EOF not reached
    read from file until space or newline reached
    check if last letter is an 'h'

    if it is
        check if it's a valid number

        if it is
            write to output file '0x'
            write to output file the number without last letter

            continue loop
        end if
    else
        write word to output file
    end if
end while
```

I don't know MIPS assembly, but I'm quite good at x86, if this can help...

Comment: if we consider a file without spaces.. eg. 101J05A3hBde where the output should be 101J0x05A3Bde then how would you change your pseudo code.

Comment: @DinMan: actually I have no idea. ;) Probably I am wrong, but there shouldn't be spaces in a bmp (which is an image) right? Still better, what is a 'space'?

Comment: my question is regarding your pseudo code.. in the second line you wrote "read from file until space or newline reached" so my question is.. a file with data without any blank spaces like..eg. 101J05A3hBde where the output should be 101J0x05A3Bde detecting the hexadecimal number and replacing it to c-style with 0x in front, then how would you change your pseudo code

Comment: @DinMan: Oh sorry, I was thinking about another question. ;) Anyway, I don't think that an assembler would accept 101J05A3hBde as a numeric constant. You said the input file is an assembly source, so I suppose it can be assembled without errors. Am I wrong?